# Special characters in SQLiteDatabase android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, special-characters

I am at the verge of finishing my first android app. But I am stuck wondering something about saving special characters in SQLite Database.

When I take data from a edit view and put that data into my database, I am able to input all the special characters without handling anything.
for eg.

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
String name = editText1.getText().toString();
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO DETAILS VALUES('" + name + "');");
```

Now the **PROBLEM**

even if I input ), (, ", * or any other special character, its able to insert that data
**BUT** as soon as I enter ' (apostrophe), there is an error(Log shows syntax). I have read almost every question related to special characters on stackoverflow but still I am not able to understand that even using ( or ) or " should generate a syntax error, same as in the case of apostrophe. Then why does it happen. Even though it works for me, but I am curios. Also what is the best way to escape these special characters ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not use `execSQL()` for this!

[`SQLiteDatabase.insert()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) will build the statement for you, and also avoid any problem with special characters in the parameters.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("FIELD_NAME", name);
db.insert("DETAILS", null, values);
```

To understand what is happening, just check what is the resulting SQL statement from adding the parameter:

- name = Scarlett -> `INSERT INTO DETAILS VALUES('Scarlett');` (Ok)
- name = O'Hara -> `INSERT INTO DETAILS VALUES('O'Hara');` (Wrong)

Since the apostrophe is the string delimiter in SQL, there is one `'O'` string plus `Hara'` which is not a valid token. In this case it just produces an error, but a maliciously crafted string could produce valid SQL which does unintended things.

That's why concatenating strings is a VERY BAD PRACTICE (TM) when writing SQL statements, as it can lead to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Remember the story of Bobby Tables!

[image]

Comment: I prefer `execSQL()` and `rawQuery()`. When **properly used**. I really hate db.* methods. I feel I have more control with complex queries by using `execSQL()` and `rawQuery()`.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Which is _very rarely_... :/ And for joins and complicated queries I would understand. But this certainly isn't.

Comment: I **never** use the `db.*` methods - it's my way of doing it. I **always** use the `execSQL()` and `rawQuery()` methods. With bound parameters (**?**). So I don't even have to care about the **'**.

Comment: @matiash sir, but if I put " in my name then it will be -> "INSERT INTO DETAILS VALUES('Scarlett"s');" how can this be valid. Will it not be an illegal statement ?

Comment: @Abhinav Double quotes are not string delimiters in SQL. Therefore, they can be inside a string, like (, *, or any other symbol, except a single quote. So, no problem.

Comment: Sir, thanks a lot. Just confirming this for the last time for a string I only will have to handle and apostrophe. Sorry, my first app so a little apprehensive. Also can you suggest me a document or page that I should read to understand better ! thanks again

Comment: @Abhinav Understand better what exactly? :) SQL? SQLite in Android? Or this in particular?

Comment: this in particular cause I am not able to find some quality document regarding these special characters any where

Comment: @Abhinav http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html _A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the backslash character are not supported because they are not standard SQL._

Comment: I'm using db.insert like suggested above but it fails with characters like  / , & ...etc.

Answer (score 3):

To enter an apostrophe, you have to double it ('').
Because an apostrophe is a special character which delimits SQL strings.

So:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO DETAILS VALUES('" + name + "')";
db.execSQL(sql.replaceAll("'", "''"));
```

Even better, you could bind your parameter:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO DETAILS VALUES (?)", new String[]{name});
```

The **?** is replaced and converted by the parameter passed as `new String[]{name}`
So, you don't even have to care about the **'** characters in your string.

---

To answer the question in your comments:
A valid **SQL String** might be:

```
'This is an apostrophe: ''; this is a quote: "; this is an asterisk: *, ...'
```

Comment: Sir, but my main question is mainly regarding why other characters are allowed.

Comment: `as soon as I enter ' (apostrophe), there is an error(Log shows syntax).` I thought you wanted to **fix this**. As far as I know, the only character you might be wanting to worry about is **'**. The other characters are normal in strings and don't give any issue while inserting them.

Comment: sir, true that I have to solve that. But more than the problem its something else thats troubling me. Why is " ( ) allowed

Comment: because it's **not** a special character, as **'** is.

Comment: you mean to say that, we have to handle only an apostrophe in case of SQLite

Comment: Yes. A valid **SQL String** might be: `'This is an apostrophe: ''; this is a quote: "; this is an asterisk: *, ...'`